# Pandas: Adding data from multiple rows into extra columns seperated by a 3rd column

Tags: python, pandas

Yesterday I got some help on how to add data from multiple rows into extra columns [Pandas: Adding data from multiple rows into extra columns for a single row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58904250/pandas-adding-data-from-multiple-rows-into-extra-columns-for-a-single-row)). That benefited me a lot, but I want to try my luck and ask for even more help.

The actual dataset I have consists of another column (country_id). For each row I want the value of the other rows within the same country_id to be added in the value_2 and value_3 column.

Below shows the data frame I currently have

```
country_id   id   value
   1         1    25
   1         2    40
   1         3    30
   2         1    15
   2         2    20
   2         3    10
```

Ideally I would like to convert it to this:

```
country_id  id  value  value_2  value_3
1           1   25     40        30
1           2   40     25        30
1           3   30     25        40
2           1   15     20        10
2           2   20     15        10
2           3   10     15        20
```

- In the 1st row: value_2 = the value of country_id = 1, id =1. value_3 = the value of id = 3 and country_id = 1.
- In the 2nd row: value_2 = the value of id = 1, country_id = 1. Value_3 = the value of id=3 and country_id = 1.
- In the 3rd row: value_2 = the value of id=1 and country_id = 1, value_3 = the value of id=2 and country_id = 1

Row 4 to 6 follow the same logic but for country_id2.

The previous solution (which didn't include country_id) worked like this:

```
repeats = np.tile(df['value'].values, (len(df), 1))

# remove elements from the diagonal
m = repeats.shape[0]
data = repeats[~np.eye(len(df), dtype=bool)].reshape(m, -1)

# create new DataFrame
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data[:, :], columns='value_' + df['id'].astype(str)[1:])

# concat old and new data
result = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)

print(result)
```

While very helpful, it still means I have to loop over each country_id and add value_2 and value_3 for one country_id at the time. I wonder if there is a method that can generate all the extra values without relying on a loop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: looping will help on to read the value of corresponding column, I do not think without looping you can read the value and can add further as a column.

Comment: Yeh perhaps you are right. Would help save a lot of time since I have quite a lot of rows if there was a smart way to avoid this.